# Why not (almost) always use Atomic*FieldUpdater?

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

Most articles I've read claim that by using Atomic*FieldUpdaters (e.g, AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater or AtomicIntegerFieldUpdater) alongside with a volatile variable of the respective type, [I'll be saving memory](http://normanmaurer.me/blog/2013/10/28/Lesser-known-concurrent-classes-Part-1/). If this is the case, it would seem that I should favor these classes over AtomicReferences and AtomicIntegers. Is this truly the case? What are some pragmatic reasons *not* to use Atomic*FieldUpdaters?

Comment: Pragmatic would be that it's less maintainable (you must maintain a string reference to a field name), and that it's more verbose than the former solution. The former solution will work just as well while consuming _bytes_ more memory, which shouldn't result in a judgement call against all variables but rather ones where you use these atomics _heavily_ and _in great numbers_. One size fits all is rarely the case in programming.